# PHP: package dependencies in a single file

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm developing a small php app that should be distributed as a single php file, which is the best way to manage external dependencies?

What if I want to include an external library? How can I package all I need in a single file?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Look into Phars http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php

Comment: @MateuszSip I'm developing an assessment tool for already installed websites. I need something that I can pass to a client and say "take that file and put it in your root". That's way... it has few sense for a developer perspective, but it has in a support management one.

Comment: Thanks @Asperon; phars achieve what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a Phar file is the best option.

Usually .phar files are executed from a command line but they can also be interpreted by web servers.

You have to configure your server to make sure it manages the .phar extension as a php file. If you can't do that you can use a simple .php file that includes the .phar via a regular `include('file.phar');`.